# PowerShell console not autocompleting

Tags: powershell

The console provides tab-completion for member names on some commands, but does not for others. Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Using Get-ChildItem has tab-completion for `FullName`.

```
PS C:\src\t> (Get-ChildItem -Path '.' -Filter 't*.txt').FullName
C:\src\t\t.4.5.txt
C:\src\t\t.txt
C:\src\t\teepee.txt
C:\src\t\test.txt
PS C:\src\t> (Test-Connection -ComputerName localhost -Count 1).responsetime
```

However, Test-Connection will not tab-complete `ResponseTime`. Typing only `respons` and pressing TAB does not autocomplete.

```
PS C:\src\t> (Test-Connection -ComputerName localhost -Count 1).responsetime
0
PS C:\src\t> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.17763.1007
```

This is on a company machine where nothing past PowerShell 5 has been permitted.

Comment: When I compare the results of Get-Member on Test-Connection, the results are different between ps5 and 7. Ps7 has no ResponseTime.

Is it possible the autocomplete on your console is set up for ps 7?

Comment: I can at least confirm, that this is normal.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping, nothing past PS 5 has been permitted on the machine.

Comment: @Thomas, does your confirmation mean that it is not supposed to tab-complete on Test-Connection? Or, does it just mean that it fails to tabl-complete on your machine, too?

Comment: @lit It fails on my machine, too.